# Give variable or name to process to kill not every process by this instance, but only with given name(variable)?

Tags: node.js, linux, bash, makefile, kill

I have many processes by one program ( in this case node.js processes) running. Some times i need to run several ( for example 10 nodejs processes) , i start them with Makefile. I want to be able with some bash command within my Makefile to turn off those 10 process when needed, but i dont want to kill other node.js running processes. So i can use `pkill node` but it will kill every node processes, how can i give some name or some variable for this 10 processes, to kill only them with kill -9 or pkill?

Answer (score 1):

You can store the PIDs of your child processes in a file and use it to kill them later. Example with `sleep` child processes:

```
$ cat Makefile
all: start-1 start-2 start-3

start-%:
    sleep 100 & echo "$$!" >> pids.txt

kill:
    kill -9 $$( cat pids.txt ); rm -f pids.txt
$ make
sleep 100 & echo "$!" >> pids.txt
sleep 100 & echo "$!" >> pids.txt
sleep 100 & echo "$!" >> pids.txt
$ ps
  PID TTY           TIME CMD
30331 ttys000    0:00.49 -bash
49812 ttys000    0:00.00 sleep 100
49814 ttys000    0:00.00 sleep 100
49816 ttys000    0:00.00 sleep 100
$ make kill
kill -9 $( cat pids.txt ); rm -f pids.txt
$ ps
  PID TTY           TIME CMD
30331 ttys000    0:00.50 -bash
```

Note: if you use parallel make you should pay attention to race conditions on `pids.txt` accesses.

Answer (score 0):

You could try killing the processes by there PID ([Process ID](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-ps-kill-and-nice-to-manage-processes-in-linux)):
for example:

```
# ps -ax | grep nginx
22546 ?        Ss     0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx
22953 pts/2    S+     0:00 grep nginx
29419 ?        Ss     0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
29420 ?        S      1:59 nginx: worker process
29421 ?        S      1:54 nginx: worker process
29422 ?        S      1:56 nginx: worker process
29423 ?        S      1:49 nginx: worker process
29425 ?        S      0:09 nginx: cache manager process
30796 ?        S      1:49 nginx: worker process
```

and then you can kill the process with:

```
kill 22546; kill 22953; kill ...
```

You can also capture just the PID with:

```
# ps -ax | grep nginx | cut -d' ' -f1 |
22546
24582
29419
29420
29421
29422
29423
29425
30796
```

update:

you can write the PIDs to a file and pull them back in make like this:

```
pids:
    echo ps -ax | grep nginx | cut -d' ' -f1 | > PIDs.txt \  

    FILE="/location/of/PIDs.txt" \
    old_IFS=$IFS \
    IFS=$'\n' \
    lines=($(cat FILE)) \
    IFS=$old_IFS \                                                                                       
    PID=$(echo {line[4]}) \
    kill $PID
```

Comment: when i start some processes i dont know their pids, so i need to store their pids somewhere on start and then execute the KILL -9 with this pids, how can i do this with make - start for example 10 nodes, save their pids and then for example- make killnodes - to kill only this nodes ?